# how do I get the salt out of my chinese take out

Tags: food-science, salt, chinese-cuisine

I bought some overly salted Chinese food ( I did not know it at time) and took most of it home.
Now I would like to get the salt out so i can it eat. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: maybe not just salty, but also overmuch msg that you detect

Answer (score 23):

While Erlenmeyer flasks and graduated cylinders and food-science may not be able to save your leftovers, adding some cooked rice with fried egg (basically any fried rice recipe) will likely crowd out the saltiness of the base dish as well as extend your leftovers.

Comment: you could add cooked rice and a fried egg to anything and i'd be happy!

Answer (score 8):

You cannot remove salt once it is in your food, so you either mix it with something else as @mfg says, or throw it away. I'd just chuck it and never grace that restaurant with your presence again.

Comment: *And* complain with the restaurant.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how salty the food really is, you could attenuate it with something that is acidic (i.e. vinegars, citrus) but if it is really too salty to eat alone then you my friend are SOL unless you want to make Chinese leftover soup and dilute it with water.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to try. My favorite is to add sugar to the food. Also, you can rinse with warm water if you don't mind losing other flavors too. Stir frying with rice or noodles works too.

Answer (score -1):

We accidentally added too much mountain seasoning to fried rice. So, we rinsed it with boiling water and that took the excess saltiness out without losing the flavors.

Comment: Golden Mountain seasoning sauce, you mean?

Comment: How did you maintain the texture? Sauteed/fried things tend to get the unpleasant kind of greasy if water is added....